# How to handle zero length vector in split component

Tags: ab-initio

I am working on creating a generic application to handle any vectored data.

The application is working fine in Normal scenario...  But the split component I am using is failing to handle a zero length vector.

Kindly share your views n suggestions...!

Answer (score 0):

Any vectored data can be handled by the Normalize component.
Use the length function in Normalize to handle zero length vectors where you can explicitly keep the length as 1 and get all other fields as a record for zero length vectors.